# App not compatible with buildpack

Tags: git, heroku

Когда делаю

```
git push heroku master
```

Вылазит это

```
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 238 bytes | 238.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to botipz.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/****.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/****.git'
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `requirements.txt` и `Procfile`, а также проверьте, установили ли вы соответствующий `buildpack`